# Change the default error message for data type in mvc3

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, attributes, types

I'm developing in mvc 3 and have a little question.
I want to change the default error message for invalid data type.
let say I've a model with the prop Price, and I want his error message for input "aaa" will be "The only value you can enter here is a number".

what is the easiest way of doing that?
(I want to do it for all of my models)

Answer (score 4):

You could use a Regular Expression data annotation on your model property, e.g.:

```
[RegularExpression(@"^[0-9\.]*$", ErrorMessage="The only value you can enter here is a number")]
public double Price { get; set; }
```

You should approach validation from a white list point of view - i.e. what should be allowed through, as opposed to a black list, which would be what is invalid.

More information here:

http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-music-store-part-6

Hope this helps!

Sam

Comment: It doesn't works, keep getting: `The value 'a' is not valid...` rather than the ErrorMessage property.

Answer (score 2):

http://haacked.com/archive/2011/03/19/fixing-binding-to-decimals.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are working with entity framework or Linq to SQL and your class name is Product. here is the example for that. create a partial class like below;

```
[MetadataType(typeof(Product.MetaData))]
public partial class Product {

    private class MetaData {

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "The only value you can enter here is a number")]
        public decimal Price { get; set; }


    }

}
```

you should add the following using statement in order to use dataanotations for validation;

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
```

Comment: that will work only for nulls not for chars and strings! thanks anyway