# Overriding default double error message with data annotations

Tags: asp.net-mvc

In my view model I have this very simple member,

```
[RegularExpression(@"^[0-9\.]*$", 
   ErrorMessage = "The only value you can enter here is a number")]
public double salary{ get; set; }
```

but when I put a value like 'abc' into the textbox, I receive this error message,

> The value 'abc' is not valid for salary.

which is not the error message I've defined. Is there some sort of default behavior that you can't overwrite with annotations? Do I have to write a custom validator?

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5548784/change-the-default-error-message-for-data-type-in-mvc3) is very similar to yours. And specifically I'd suggest seeing [Phil Haack's Blog post](http://haacked.com/archive/2011/03/19/fixing-binding-to-decimals.aspx) on a related topic.

Answer (score 3):

Before the field is validated against your regular expression, it is being validated to ensure that it is the correct type. Since 'abc' can't be converted to a double, you get that error message.

You could make `salary` a string and then parse it into a double in your controller, that will prevent the conversion and allow your Regex error message to be displayed when an invalid value is entered.

Otherwise, use `Html.ValidationMessageFor` to override the validation message

```
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.salary, "The only value you can enter here is a number")
```

Comment: How can I change the default message though, when it checks if it's the correct type?

Comment: @systemic, see update. You can try using the Html.ValidationMessageFor html helper

Comment: I just found that, actually - the only issue is if I use that, it doesn't appear in the ValidationSummary, which is actually the *only* place I want it to appear...I can't win.

Answer (score 1):

RegularExpression should be used for string type, it will not be called for a double type since it is not possible to assign 'abc' to a double in the first place.